# How to use math operation with 2 props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Example : I want to multiply 2 props that was fetch from API ( Temp*
Humidity) and want to update the result when new value is come(user input new city then temp and humidity changed)

Here's my fetching.js

```
fetchData = q => {
fetch(
  `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${q},th&units=metric&APPID=${API_KEY}`
)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({
      currentWeather: {
        temp: json.main.temp,
        icon: json.weather[0].icon,
        description: json.weather[0].description,
        humidity: json.main.humidity,
        datetime: json.dt
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.warn(error);
  });
};
```

And here's my frontend

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
        <View style={styles.dataStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Temperature </Text>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.temp} °C</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.dataStyle}>

      <Image
            style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
            source={{
          uri: `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${this.props.icon}.png`
        }}
      />
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.description}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.dataStyle}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Humidity</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.humidity} %</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
```

I want to calculate heat index when temp and humidity is pass to component and show on the humidity section instead.

Comment: What is the difficult you are facing trying to implement this?

Comment: Simply set a new `currentWeather` property named `heatIndex` and set it to `json.main.temp * json.mainhumidy`. Why won't that work?

Comment: Sorry I'm new for javascript. I just know basic about state and props but I don't know what that can do.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your fetch within the componentDidMount() lifecycle event.  If any data in state changes, then the component will be rerendered.

> componentDidMount is executed after the first render only on the client side. This is where AJAX requests and DOM or state updates should occur. This method is also used for integration with other JavaScript frameworks and any functions with delayed execution such as setTimeout or setInterval. We are using it to update the state so we can trigger the other lifecycle methods.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_component_life_cycle.htm

Comment: Thank you. I need to practice life cycle more and more.

Comment: @artaro don't hesitate to upvote and tick it as resolved if you consider it is the good answer to your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply `props` when `props` passed into component, then use **componentWillReceiveProps** method.

whenever new props is received to component, the **componentWillReceiveProps** method will be executed.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(Props) {
          let heat_index = props.Temp* props.Humidity;
          this.setState({heat_index : heat_index});
        }

    render() {
        return (
       <View>
      <Text> The Heat Index is {this.state.heat_index} </Text>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: @artaro don't hesitate to upvote and tick it as resolved if you consider it is the good answer to your problem